# SQL query contains redundant Where and On conditions - do they have a purpose or do they slow the query?

Tags: sql

I'm editing a SQL query, and encountered a part that roughly resembles the following:

```
SELECT 
    userAddress, employeeAddress, userSSNumber,  
    employeeSSNumber, customerSSNumber, userID, employeeWorkHours, 
    YTDHoursWorked, employeeHireDate
FROM  
    Users
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Customers ON customerSSNumber = userSSNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         employeeAddress AS Address,
         ISNULL((SELECT SUM(employeeWorkHours) 
                 FROM Employees AS TempLines 
                 WHERE TempLines.employeeSSNumber = Employees.employeeSSNumber 
                   AND Templines.employeeHireDate < Employees.employeeHireDate), 0) AS YTDHoursWorked 
     FROM
         Employees) AS Records ON employeeAddress = Address
```

I suspect that the parts

```
where TempLines.employeeSSNumber= Employees.employeeSSNumber
```

and

```
on employeeAddress = Address
```

are completely redundant. If I understand correctly, they are just comparing the value to itself, and the query will return the same results if I delete those bits – is that right?

And, the

```
Templines.employeeHireDate < Employees.employeeHireDate
```

part will cause the nested-most Select to return no results at all, right?

Please forgive any inconsistent capitalization in my example, and the poor design and naming conventions of the tables. The actual query is far, far longer due to many of these possibly-redundant parts. It uses these naming conventions, and I can’t change any of the tables or fields. Part of this question is as a sanity check after staring at page-long queries for a few hours.

Comment: always specify tag for your database engine and the version

Comment: What does this query suppose to do? looks like it finds total worked hours before the employee get hired! also join condition on "employeeAddress = Address" looks suspicious. why it is not joining on key field to SSN?

Comment: The query is used to gather a handful of fields that are used for one report in Crystal Reports. This query just collects about 30 fields from 6 tables, sums a few of them, and puts them into a single table that Crystal Reports analyzes. 
My predecessors and/or the ERP makers decided to manually write their SQL queries for Crystal Reports. That's not how Crystal Reports is supposed to be used (as far as I know), but it's how they did it. If I overlook something and no one catches the error, that will change the employee's commission or even change in manpower (i.e., terminations).

Comment: the clause "TempLines.employeeSSNumber = Employees.employeeSSNumber" is part of a correlated sub query. it makes sure that the sum on the line is only for the given line. if you take it out, it will put the same sum on every employees record. Did you try it to see what would happen?

Comment: Jeremy, so if I understand correctly, the "TempLines" alias is critical and it allows that clause to translate in plain English to "where THIS employee's SSN = any employee's SSN"? It separates the iteration of the parent loop from the iteration of the nested loop.
If so, that explains why it is there. I just wish it was easier to read.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I'm not sure of the purpose of the hiredate clause, but if you're getting information I'm assuming it must do something.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, if you want to put that as an answer, it's the correct one. The HireDate clause is actually from this in the original query, and I suspect that translates to "if the transaction was part of an earlier fiscal period": 
    ((TempLines.gllGLFiscalYearPeriodID <= GLJournalLines.gllGLFiscalYearPeriodID and
     TempLines.gllTransactionDate < GLJournalLines.gllTransactionDate) Or (TempLines.gllGLFiscalYearPeriodID < GLJournalLines.gllGLFiscalYearPeriodID))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clause "TempLines.employeeSSNumber = Employees.employeeSSNumber" is part of a correlated sub query. it makes sure that the sum on the line is only for the given line.